# Asymptotic normality of the maximum likelihood estimator with dependent data

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, central-limit-theorem, martingale

In the setup, assume $\left(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right), P\right)$ is the underlying probability space and suppose that $\left\{\mathcal{F_n}\right\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a filtration inside the Borel sets.

I am interested in recovering the asymptotic normality of a maximum likelihood estimator with dependent data using a martingale central limit theorem. Let $\left\{P_\theta\right\}_{\theta \in \Theta}$ be a family of mutually absolutely continuous measures on $\mathscr{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ where $\Theta \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an open interval. Further assume that $P_\theta \ll P$ for all $\theta \in \Theta$. Define
$$ l_n\left(\theta\right) :=  \log\left(\mathbb{E}_P\left[\frac{dP_\theta}{dP} \mid \mathcal{F}_n\right]\right) $$ as the log-likelihood function where the likelihood is a density of the restriction of the measures $P_\theta,P$ to the sub-sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}_n$. Define the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$ as a solution to $l_{n}^\prime\left(\theta\right) = 0$, assuming that the solution exists and is unique. Suppose further that the quadratic variation $$ \frac{\left[l^\prime(\theta), l^\prime(\theta)\right]_n }{n} \stackrel{p}{\to} \sigma^2 $$ where $\sigma > 0$. What assumptions and what CLT do we need to ensure that
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta \right) \to \mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^{-2}\right)
$$ and
$$ -\frac{l^{\prime\prime}_n\left(\hat{\theta}_n\right)}{n}\to \sigma^2 ?$$